# Visual Studio 2008 not detecting Errors while coding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

I just installed VS on another PC, but this time, while I am coding, it is not marking syntax errors while I am coding..... I need to press F6 to get the errors.

Normally when for example typing the line below, I get 's' underlined saying that there is a mismatch. Any ideas how I can enable this option?

```
            string s = 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable background compilation for C#, which checks you code while typing for many types of errors that are usually only reported when you build the project, you will have to install [Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E). If you use the offline MSDN, you will also want to install the updated [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7BBE5EDA-5062-4EBB-83C7-D3C5FF92A373), since there were framework changes from .NET 3.5 RTM to .NET 3.5 SP1 (such as the addition of [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you [recently deinstalled ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828477/resharper-uninstall-visual-studio-no-longer-shows-correct-error-highlighting)

(see responses in the same link for other possibilities).

Comment: thanks but none of them solved my problem. Note that this is a clean install on a new PC

Answer (score 1):

C# has never been as consistent about finding errors while i type as VB.net has.  I always assumed it was just due to the freeform nature of the language, which would also explain why C++ never found errors either til build time.